# Spring Secuirty CAS SLO not working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, cas

We use an JASIG CAS-Server for authentication. 
Single-Sign-On works fine but the Single-Logout not working how i expected it.

This are steps i do:

- GoTo http://foo.bar
- Login on http://cas.bar
- Go To http://baaar.bar
- Logout on foo.baar via cas.bar
- Go To http://baar.bar
- Still logged in

So if I log out on `http://foo.bar` it actually works and if I call it again i need to Login, but `http://baar.bar` i'm still logged in.

Here is my application Config:

```
        // Define the authentication providers
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ["casAuthenticationProvider"]
    // Define the CAS configuration
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = "/login"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://cas.bar/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix ="https://cas.bar/cas"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl =   "https://cas.bar/cas/logout?url=http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.userDetailsService = "CasUserDetailsService"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.seSessionFixationPrevention = false
```

Why i'm still logged in on `http://baar.bar`?

**EDIT**:

The Cas Server is sending an Logout Message to the applications, in the log file it prints like this:

```
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient] - <Finished sending message to https://baar.bar/j_spring_cas_security_check>
```

On the other end i see the incomming request in the log files from the apache2:

```
 "POST /j_spring_cas_security_check HTTP/1.1" 200 5655 "-" "Java/1.8.0_131"
```

Comment: I still have this problem....